Need help with what test to run
Hi everyone,
I was monitoring environmental parameters of 4 different sites every month for an entire year. I calculated mean values for these parameters and their standard deviation. I want to see if site, month, or a combination of the two impacts the values I measured. I just don't know what test to run.
For March, April, September, and October I only have data for 3 sites. I'm not sure if that changes anything. Attached is what my figure looks like for one parameter (chlorophyll). Any help is greatly appreciated, stats is not my forte (:

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to CV, ACS.  Evidently you don't need any testing (in this example) to establish the means vary over time: sometimes results are just obvious. // Why are some data missing in some months?  The reason could have an effect on how you analyze these data. // Are you sure you need a formal test?  It sounds rather like you want to explore and characterize these data.  If you do need a test, what is the statistical hypothesis you are testing?
